# How do I register a reactor on a given file descriptor?

Tags: ace

I have a file descriptor which i want the ace reactor to register on, and notify me on changes. How do I register a reactor on a given file descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example [here](http://huihoo.org/ace_tao/ACE-5.2+TAO-1.2/ACE_wrappers/docs/tutorials/Chap_5/ex01.html).  The way you do this is:

1. Create Reactor.
2. Create an object that will be subclassed from `ACE_Event_Handler` I don't think you want default implementations.
3. call `ACE_Reactor::instance()->register_handler(new_handler)`